# Django AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'splitlines'

Tags: django

I'm trying to create an user registration with email confirmation and came up with this code in the `models.py`

```
class UserRegister(SuccessMessageMixin, FormView):
template_name = 'login/form_register.html'
form_class = UserRegisterForm
redirect_authenticated_user = True
success_url = reverse_lazy('tasks')
success_message = "User has been created, please login"

def form_valid(self, form):
    user = form.save(commit=False)
    user.is_active = False # Deactivate account till it is confirmed
    user.save()

    current_site = get_current_site(self.request)
    subject = 'Activate Your Account'
    message = render_to_string('login/account_activation_email.html'), {
        'user':user,
        'domain':current_site.domain,
        'uid':urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(user.pk)),
        'token':account_activation_token.make_token(user),
    }
    
    user.email_user(subject, message)

    messages.add_message(
        self.request,
        messages.SUCCESS,
        'Check Your Email For Account Activation Link'
    ) 

    if user is not None:
        login(self.request, user)
    return super(UserRegister, self).form_valid(form)

def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if self.request.user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect('tasks')
    return super(UserRegister, self).get(*args, **kwargs)
```

But I keep getting this error `AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'splitlines'`

This is the traceback

```
Internal Server Error: /register/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ihzacordova/.local/share/virtualenvs/todo-list-KiFNCv1Z/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 55, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/ihzacordova/.local/share/virtualenvs/todo-list-KiFNCv1Z/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 197, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/ihzacordova/.local/share/virtualenvs/todo-list-KiFNCv1Z/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 103, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ihzacordova/.local/share/virtualenvs/todo-list-KiFNCv1Z/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 142, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ihzacordova/.local/share/virtualenvs/todo-list-KiFNCv1Z/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py", line 153, in post
    return self.form_valid(form)
  File "/home/ihzacordova/projects/todo-list/login/models.py", line 52, in form_valid
    user.email_user(subject, message)
  File "/home/ihzacordova/.local/share/virtualenvs/todo-list-KiFNCv1Z/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 402, in email_user
    send_mail(subject, message, from_email, [self.email], **kwargs)
  File "/home/ihzacordova/.local/share/virtualenvs/todo-list-KiFNCv1Z/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/mail/__init__.py", line 87, in send_mail
    return mail.send()
  File "/home/ihzacordova/.local/share/virtualenvs/todo-list-KiFNCv1Z/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/mail/message.py", line 298, in send
    return self.get_connection(fail_silently).send_messages([self])
  File "/home/ihzacordova/.local/share/virtualenvs/todo-list-KiFNCv1Z/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/mail/backends/smtp.py", line 131, in send_messages
    sent = self._send(message)
  File "/home/ihzacordova/.local/share/virtualenvs/todo-list-KiFNCv1Z/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/mail/backends/smtp.py", line 147, in _send
    message = email_message.message()
  File "/home/ihzacordova/.local/share/virtualenvs/todo-list-KiFNCv1Z/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/mail/message.py", line 260, in message
    msg = SafeMIMEText(self.body, self.content_subtype, encoding)
  File "/home/ihzacordova/.local/share/virtualenvs/todo-list-KiFNCv1Z/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/mail/message.py", line 160, in __init__
    MIMEText.__init__(self, _text, _subtype=_subtype, _charset=_charset)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/email/mime/text.py", line 42, in __init__
    self.set_payload(_text, _charset)
  File "/home/ihzacordova/.local/share/virtualenvs/todo-list-KiFNCv1Z/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/mail/message.py", line 170, in set_payload
    for line in payload.splitlines()
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'splitlines'
```

Comment: Can you post your whole model method of `user.email_user(subject, message)`

Comment: @hanspeters205 I can't actually got it from this tutorial https://studygyaan.com/django/how-to-signup-user-and-send-confirmation-email-in-django. I also tried this ```EmailMessage(to=[user.email], subject=subject, body=message).send()``` from this tutorial https://www.rockandnull.com/django-email-verification/. Same error unfortunately

Comment: Right, I realized it's a built-in method. `message` must be a string. However in your code it's a tuple. Check the wrong placed `)` in my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
message = render_to_string('login/account_activation_email.html'), {
    'user':user,
    'domain':current_site.domain,
    'uid':urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(user.pk)),
    'token':account_activation_token.make_token(user),
}
```

To

```
message = render_to_string('login/account_activation_email.html', {
    'user':user,
    'domain':current_site.domain,
    'uid':urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(user.pk)),
    'token':account_activation_token.make_token(user),
})
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, it works fine now. Thanks a lot man!